# How can I merge arrays with along an identifier?

Tags: php, arrays, function

I have two arrays like this:

```
$arr1 = ['yellow' => 1, 'red', => 5];
$arr2 = ['gray' => 3, 'black' => 8, 'orange' => 6, 'yellow' => 9];
```

And I want this result:

```
$merged = ['yellow' => [1, 'arr1'], 'red', => [5, 'arr1'], 'gray' => [3, 'arr2'], 'black' => [8, 'arr2'], 'orange' => [6, 'arr2'], 'yellow' =>  [9, 'arr2']];
```

But as I've read the documentation about [`array_merge()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php),it doesn't have such a option. Is there any function to do that for me?

Comment: can yellow be found in both arr1 and arr2?? or whatever color

Comment: @Vanojx1 yes . . . ! They aren't unique and I need to keep both of them

Answer (score 2):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
<?php
$input = [
    'arr1' => ['yellow' => 1, 'red' => 5],
    'arr2' => ['yellow' => 10, 'gray' => 3, 'black' => 8, 'orange' => 6]
];
$output = [];
array_walk($input, function ($entry, $source) use (&$output) {
    foreach ($entry as $key=>$val) {
        $output[$key][] = [$val, $source];
    }
});
print_r($output);
```

The output of above code obviously is:

```
Array
(
    [yellow] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => arr1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 10
                    [1] => arr2
                )

        )

    [red] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 5
                    [1] => arr1
                )

        )

    [gray] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3
                    [1] => arr2
                )

        )

    [black] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 8
                    [1] => arr2
                )

        )

    [orange] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 6
                    [1] => arr2
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: @stack Hope you are fine and things develop as you wish ;-)

Comment: This code does not work correctly if 'yellow' occurs in both arrays. It doesn't keep both values, but overwrites.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware in that case what will be output?

Comment: @Chetan: The output is too long for a comment... but if you want to know, try the code.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Certainly possible too with a trivial modification. I adapted the answer accordingly. The question itself did not specify that requirement which is why I implemented exactly what was asked. This modification obviously changes the output format definition.

Comment: @stack Not sure what you are actually looking for, but either way, that is only a detail, the general idea should be more than clear.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it took me a bit longer to come up with this answer because you have a bug in your question. See the ',' behind 'red' in array 1.

```
$arr1 = ['yellow' => 1, 'red' => 5];
$arr2 = ['gray' => 3, 'black' => 8, 'yellow' => 3, 'orange' => 6];

$arrays = ['arr1','arr2'];
$merged = [];

foreach ($arrays as $array) {
  foreach (${$array} as $color => $value) {
    $merged[$color][] = [$value,$array];
  }
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($merged);
echo '</pre>';
```

To keep both values of 'yellow' I introduced an extra layer of arrays. I don't see how to keep them otherwise.

So the code was tested and returns:

```
Array
(
    [yellow] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => arr1
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3
                    [1] => arr2
                )
        )
    [red] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 5
                    [1] => arr1
                )
        )
    [gray] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 3
                    [1] => arr2
                )
        )
    [black] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 8
                    [1] => arr2
                )
        )
    [orange] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 6
                    [1] => arr2
                )
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @arkascha answer a version that handle duplicates:

```
<?php
  $input = [
    'arr1'=> ['yellow' => 1,'red' => 5, 'black' => 4],
    'arr2'=> ['gray' => 3,'yellow' => 3, 'black' => 8,'orange' => 6],
    'arr3'=> ['orange' => 2]
  ];

  $output = [];
  array_walk($input, function ($entry, $source) use (&$output) {
    foreach ($entry as $key=>$val) {
      if(!array_key_exists($key, $output))
        $output[$key] = [[$val, $source]];
      else
        $output[$key][] = [$val, $source];
    }
  });

  echo print_r($output);

?>
```

[PHP FIDDLE](https://repl.it/Gvij/0)